# How to unsubscribe Single Observable in RxJava

Tags: android, rx-android, rx-java2

I am looking to unsubscribe the Rx Singles after the operation.
This is how I have unsubscribed Observable in RxJava.

```
public class BooksRepositoryImpl implements IBooksRepository {


    private ReplaySubject<Book> bookSubject;
    private Subscription bookSubscription;

    BooksApi BooksApi;
    ISchedulerProvider scheduler;

    @Inject
    public BooksRepositoryImpl(BooksApi BooksApi, ISchedulerProvider scheduler) {
        this.BooksApi = BooksApi;
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Book> getBooks(String author) {

        if (bookSubscription == null || bookSubscription.isUnsubscribed()) {
            bookSubscription = ReplaySubject.create();

            bookSubscription = BooksApi.getBooks(author)
                    .subscribeOn(scheduler.backgroundThread());
        }

        return bookSubscription.asObservable();


    }


    @Override
    public void unbind() {

        if (bookSubscription != null && !bookSubscription.isUnsubscribed())
            bookSubscription.unsubscribe();

    }

}
```

But I am not sure how to unsubscribe the Single Observable.
It would be great if someone can able to share some idea.

```
public class BooksRepositoryImpl implements IBooksRepository {

BooksApi BooksApi;
ISchedulerProvider scheduler;

@Inject
public BooksRepositoryImpl(BooksApi BooksApi, ISchedulerProvider scheduler) {
    this.BooksApi = BooksApi;
    this.scheduler = scheduler;
}

@Override
public Single<Book> getBooks(String author) {

    return BooksApi.getBooks(author)
            .subscribeOn(scheduler.backgroundThread());

}


@Override
public void unbind() {
    //?? HOW Can I unsubscribe here
}
```

}

Comment: Possibly the duplicate of another question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47862794/3282461)

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation [Single](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html), you should do nothing, the subscription end by itself:

> A Single will call only one of these methods, and will only call it
>   once. Upon calling either method, the Single terminates and the
>   subscription to it ends.

Hope this helps.
Sorry for my english.