# What's the correct way to unsubscribe from Single

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to do something after short delay:

```
public void notifyMe() {
Single
       .timer(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
       .subscribe(ignore -> service.notifyMe()));
}
```

Now I have a warning: `"The result of subscribe is not used"`.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Wait, but in my example will be emitted only one value.

Comment: Is this in an Android application? If so, you should add the result to a `CompositeDisposable`.

Comment: @akarnokd, whats's different between android and java (java test / console application, etc) in this case? And how can help me CompositeDisposable? Anyway somebody should call dispose. So, my question: method scubscribe() return me Disposable, I should call it after I send notify, right?

Comment: Android has more strict lifecycle and have to be extra careful with leaking flows. On desktop Swing, you should also do `CompositeDisposable.add()` when doing actions in a window that can be closed by the user. You should call `dispose` when the action is no longer needed to happen. If you call it immediately, the notification won't happen.

Comment: Sorry @YuraShinkarev but I thought you were trying to subscribe, not unsubscribe, so my previous comment was not relevant.

Comment: @akarnokd I wrote `notifyMe` function. I want in background after short delay did some job (service.notifyMe). My public function do not return any variable. I want call and "forgot". So, I want implement with rxjava same: new Thread(new Runnable(){...}).start() or in android: new AsyncTask().execute().

Comment: Just suppress that warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Single will only call once. Upon calling either method, the Single terminates and the subscription to it ends.

[Link](http://reactivex.io/documentation/single.html) can be referred for more information.