# Single.zip - How to catch failed call and continue the rest of network calls?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm making 5 parallel network calls, mocking 4 of them to succeed and one of them to fail.

The failed call makes the entire `Single.zip()` fail and I can't get the results of the 4 other network calls even though they have succeeded.

How can I handle the error for the single failed network call in the `Single.zip()` and get the results of the ones that have succeeded?

```
private Single<BigInteger> createNetworkCall(){
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            
            return service.getBalance("validaddress").execute();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

```
private Single<BigInteger> createFailedNetworkCall(){
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            
            return service.getBalance("invalidaddress").execute();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

```
private void makeParallelCalls(){
        List<Single<BigInteger>> iterable = new ArrayList<>();
        iterable.add(createNetworkCall());
        iterable.add(createNetworkCall());
        iterable.add(createNetworkCall());
        iterable.add(createNetworkCall());
        iterable.add(createFailedNetworkCall());

        Single.zip(iterable, (results) -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "makeParallelCalls: " + Arrays.toString(results));
            return results;
        }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(results-> {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: makeParallelCalls: " + results);

                }, (exception) -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onError: makeParallelCalls", exception);

                });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch the exception and don't allow the error to interrupt the Single.zip.

For example inside your request factory, return an Optional instead of the response.

```
private Single<Optional<Long>> performNetworkCall(int n){
    return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            throw new Exception("failed call");
        }
        return 0L;
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .map(Optional::of)
    .onErrorReturnItem(Optional.empty());
    // or .onErrorReturn(exception -> Optional.empty());
}

private void makeParallelCalls(){
    List<Single<BigInteger>> iterable = new ArrayList<>();
    iterable.add(performNetworkCall(1));
    iterable.add(performNetworkCall(2));
    iterable.add(performNetworkCall(3));
    iterable.add(performNetworkCall(4));
    iterable.add(performNetworkCall(5));

    Single.zip(iterable, (results) -> {
                for (Object result : results) {
                    var optional = (Optional<Integer>)result;
                    if (optional.isEmpty()) {
                        // this one failed, no data
                    } else {
                        var response = optional.get();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            });
}
```

You could replace the Optional with a custom class that holds additional information, such as the exception or error information that caused the failure.

If you have recovery options, you could use `.onErrorResumeNext`instead.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it. Your answer is much better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to RxJava so I don't know if there is a more better solution or if this is a really bad practice, but I used the `onErrorReturn` callback on the `Single`.

If someone has a better solution, please share so I can mark yours correct!

```
public static final int INVALID_USER_ADDRESS = -101;
```

```
private Single<BigInteger> createNetworkCall(){
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            
            return service.getBalance("validaddress").execute();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
}
```

```
private Single<BigInteger> createFailedNetworkCall(){
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> {
            
            return service.getBalance("invalidaddress").execute();
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).onErrorReturn(throwable -> {
            if(throwable instanceof IllegalArgumentException){
                return BigInteger.valueOf(INVALID_USER_ADDRESS);
            }else{
                return BigInteger.valueOf(-100);
            }
        });;
}
```

```
private void makeParallelCalls(){
        List<Single<BigInteger>> iterable = new ArrayList<>();
        iterable.add(createNetworkCall());
        iterable.add(createNetworkCall());
        iterable.add(createNetworkCall());
        iterable.add(createNetworkCall());
        iterable.add(createFailedNetworkCall());

        Single.zip(iterable, (results) -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "makeParallelCalls: " + Arrays.toString(results));
            return results;
        }).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(results-> {

                    for(int i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                        if(results[i].equals(INVALID_USER_ADDRESS)){
                            //Handle error here
                            
                        }else{
                            //Handle success value here
                            
                        }
                    }
                }, (exception) -> {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onError: makeParallelCalls", exception);

                });
}
```

`.subscribe(results-> {`

returns:

`[2583397195825000000000, 2583397195825000000000, 2583397195825000000000, 2583397195825000000000, -101]`